# How to set icon content of pseudo element by its attribute?

Tags: html, css, icomoon

I'm using icomoon as my icon library

And I'm trying to dynamically set icons by the attribute `data-icon`.

But it seems the content can't be recognized as a charset using `attr(data-icon)`.

Is there a way to make `\e92c` as a character rather than string literal using `attr()`?

```css
#expected::before {
  content: '\e92c';
  font-family: 'icomoon';
}

[data-icon]::before {
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-family: 'icomoon';
}
```

```html
<h2>This is what I expected</h2>
<a class="button" id="expected" href="javascript: void(0)">Save</a>

<h2>This is what I get :(</h2>
<a class="button" data-icon="\e92c" href="javascript: void(0)">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML text is escaped differently from CSS text. In the attribute, you want `&#xE92C;` for the equivalent hex excape (what the spec calls a "decimal character reference" or a "hexadecimal character reference;" [details here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references)).

Hexadecimal character reference (note the `x` after the `#`):

```
data-icon="&#xE92C;"
```

Decimal (no `x`):

```
data-icon="&#59692;"
```

Live example:

```css
#expected::before {
  content: '\00e92c';
  font-family: 'icomoon';
}

[data-icon]::before {
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-family: 'icomoon';
}
```

```html
<h2>This is what I expected</h2>
<a class="button" id="expected" href="javascript: void(0)">Save</a>

<h2>From <code>data-icon</code></h2>
<a class="button" data-icon="&#xE92C;" href="javascript: void(0)">Save</a>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that! It works great, thanks! Will be accepted in 2 min!